# Code for border of links not working the ideal way

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a buttoned-link. The concept is that the link shall have a border. The border-style will be outset. And the `a:active` will be `border-style: inset`.

When I add the following code, it shows like the image I've provided. Why isn't the border working?

```
<style>

a {
    border-style: outset; text-decoration: none; color: #000;}
a:active {
    border-style: inset; text-decoration: none; color: #000;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#divlast">
        <p>Some random text here to check the border's working.</p></a>

<div class="divlast">
        <p>The Last Division</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove p tags from link.

```
<a href="#divlast">
   Some random text here to check the border's working.
</a>
```

A element is inline element by default, but you may want to render it as a block element.

```
a {
    display: block; border-style: outset; text-decoration: none; color: #000;}
a:active {
    border-style: inset; text-decoration: none; color: #000;}
```

You shouldn't add block elements into inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues.

The first is that you're putting a `p` tag inside your anchor, which is messing up the formatting, I'm not seeing a need for that.

The second is that you're not specifying a full style for your border, which would help.

I think this is your desired result, yes?

Example **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/668sw/)**

**HTML**

```
<a href="#divlast">
    Some random text here to check the border's working.
</a>
<div class="divlast">
    <p>The Last Division</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    border:3px solid pink;
    border-style: outset; text-decoration: none; color: #000;
}
a:active {
    border-style: inset; text-decoration: none; color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Borders apply to 'block' type elements so you would have to apply some form of block formatting to the `a` tag

For instance:

**CSS**

```
a {
    border-style: outset; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
    border-style: inset; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #000;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2e3x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like that:

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/WK3XJ/1/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#divlast">
        Some random text here to check the border's working.</a>

<div class="divlast">
    <p>The Last Division</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    border: solid 3px green;
    border-style: outset;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
a:active {
    border: solid 3px green;
    border-style: inset;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```